# How to access initial values of form fields in a loop in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to display initial values of form fields in a template.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.CharField(max_length=100, initial='test')
```

When I call a specific field everything is fine, but **when I loop over form, nothing happens**.

```
{% for field in form.fields %}
    {{ field.initial }}            # output: (nothing)
{% endfor %}

{{ form.fields.myfield.initial }}  # output: 'test'
```

Is it expected behaviour? How can I access initial values in a loop?

Answer (score 2):

Loop over `form` itself.

```
{% for field in form %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.field.initial }}
{% endfor %}
```